# Description of Curious badge could be clearer - count shows 6/5

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page, badge-progress

This looks wrong to me.

[image: Curious badge incorrect count]

Clicking on the badge shows some criteria about why the badge has not been awarded but it's a bit cryptic. It would be nice to be able to click on that criteria and be taken to a page (eg [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67399#67399)) which explains it in more detail

Comment: Seems reasonable to me...considering that you're missing a requirement for the badge to be considered complete (click on the banner to see what it is).

Comment: I'm very confused about the exact criteria

Comment: [The list is here.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399/175248) I can't tell if you've got any deleted questions, but those apply twice in the formula against you.

Comment: Thanks - I've updated the question to something more relevant

Comment: @nevster: I am 1120/600 for Electorate ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why didn't I get the Curious badge?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294497/why-didnt-i-get-the-curious-badge)