# Why didn't I get the "Curious"-family badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-progress

As per the [Curious badge page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4127/curious), the badge is given for:

> Asking a good question on 5 separate days, and maintaining a positive question record.

*(replace "5" with "30" for Inquisitive and "100" for Socratic)*

The popup on the profile page is showing as

> 8/5 days asked

and the progress bar is also full. Why haven't I received the badge yet?

Comment: You still need positive question record, the first progress bar is showing that you asked 8 questions from 5 required.

Comment: but it have positive records and progress bar is full. I notice that whwn tag progress bar is full then that will given

Comment: Click on the tag progress bar. You'll see an `x` next to "need positive question record."

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Note that "x" in the below image, copied from your profile:

[image: "How is this badge earned?"]

The [formula](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251172/should-we-change-the-positive-asking-record-criteria-for-the-curious-badge-set) is:

> (total questions - negative questions - closed - early deleted)/total questions >= 0.5

Comment: That's a little stringent, especially because the downvotes or so personal and subjectively based. Maybe it should be a silver or gold badge.  :-)

Comment: @RohitGupta: On any site I could ask 5 questions, I found no difficulty asking 5 positively-scored questions before I asked 5 negatively-scored....

Comment: Are duplicates included in this formula?

Comment: Formula and its explaination should be explained then when user shown with X symbol

Comment: Where can I get this score `(total questions - negative questions - closed - early deleted)/total questions` for my profile?

Comment: Do duplicates count?

Comment: @Ṁữŀlɪgắnậcễơưṩᛗ: yes, duplicates count.

Comment: I have the same issue. In profile, it shows 6/5 days asked and when I calculated according to the above mention formula answer is 0.9 then why I don't get this badge?

Comment: How does it count if I have a question which is both negative and closed?

Comment: @MerajalMaksud As of now, I have asked 7 questions, one of them is a duplicate, and another one is negative, closed, and deleted. If I count it, it should be `(7-2)/7 = 0.7`; but I still "*need a positive question record*", and only if I count the downvoted-closed-deleted question 3 times, do I get the result: `(7-1-2-1)/7 = 0.4`. So I assume that one question can count in multiple categories at the same time.

Comment: I have the same question and I have 5/5 and according to the formula I get 0.625. How can I check whether I have any deleted questions?

Comment: Do 0 vote questions consider negative? how I can see how many closed questions I have? and if the question got downvoted but is still positive is it considered negative? @MartijnPieters

Comment: @Ahmad: the post _score_ needs to be negative. Because the score comes from votes, if a question has zero votes then there can't be a negative score. You can see all your closed questions (not including deleted) by searching for `user:me is:q closed:yes`, and you can look at your deleted questions by going to https://stackoverflow.com/users/deleted-questions/4171008. It doesn't matter if there are downvotes or upvotes, it is the score that counts. A question at score 0 is not negative.

Comment: @Ahmad: you currently have 7 questions with a negative score (including deleted questions), you have 3 closed questions (all deleted), and you have 6 (early) deleted questions. You have 25 questions in total, so your question record value is `(25 - 7 - 3 - 6) / 25 = 0.36`. You'll need 7 new questions that are not deleted, downvoted or closed to compensate for that, or you could see if you could salvage existing questions by editing them to meet our site requirements, then hope that they get upvotes over time if they have a negative score still.

Comment: Thanks for this kind and awesome reply! @MartijnPieters :) Sadly I will not try to edit any negative questions because they will get downvoted more!

Comment: If I am understand this correctly, a question that is downvoted, closed *and* deleted, will be counted 3 times here. As an example, I *don't* have the curious badge. If you only count a question once, I have a score of 0.59 (37 questions, 0 negative score (not deleted/closed), 6 closed (not deleted), and 9 deleted. if you count multiple times, then you get 37 questions, 5 negative score, 11 closed, and 9 deleted giving a score of 0.32. Is this intended?

Answer (score 25):

The style of the badge information view is a little bit confusing:

[image: current style]

I changed the style to better communicate the meaning:

[image: new style]