# Didn't obtain Inquisitive badge even for 30/30

Tags: bug, badges

I didn't obtain the badge Inquisitive even for 30/30, as shown below. Why?

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1716/how-long-does-it-take-for-badges-to-be-awarded-how-are-they-generated

Comment: You can find the answer here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294497/why-didnt-i-get-the-curious-badge

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you click on progress bar, it will tell you what you are still missing.

[image]

In this case you have not fulfilled the second requirement which is to have a positive question records.  A positive question score is:

> A positive question record means you don't have too many closed, downvoted or deleted questions, overall. The formula is `(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted) / total questions >= 0.5`. Questions that have been downvoted and closed and deleted count three times in this calculation!

<sup>[source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)</sup>

Comment: Thx. You earned my upvote.

Comment: @sparkandshine No problem.  looks like this was a dupe though.

Comment: I did search 'Inquisitive badge' on this site but didn't find these duplicate posts as mentioned.

Comment: @sparkandshine That's alright.  This should help the next person that does.

Comment: `- deleted` Does that include unanswered questions that were deleted by owner?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Yes.  It is all of the persons deleted questions.