# Can OP use the "Ask-question-wizard" to edit his question

Tags: discussion, ask-question-wizard-2018

Recently I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55589313/find-distance-between-two-strings-c-stacks) post ([screenshot for sub 10k rep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpglJ.png)). As you can see, the OP had some serious trouble formulating and formatting his question which resulted in a standard avalanche of downvotes.

As this is a new contributor, I was suggesting him to use the Wizard to ask a question. But this made me wonder:

1. Was the new contributor not suggested to use the Wizard when he clicked "Ask Question"?
2. Can the wizard be summoned by the OP to improve his question when editing?

Comment: The post is not there any longer...

Comment: @FranzHuber23 true, but the questions are still relevant.

Comment: I know. I was just curious how the post looked like ;)

Comment: @FranzHuber23 I've added a screenshot of the question :)

Comment: tbh, never in my SO life have I found out about the "[Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard)" until I saw this post. That wizard should be emphasised more strongly which would potentially improve _a lot_ of questions.

Comment: @YongQuan You haven't seen the [The Ask Question Wizard is Live!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381671/the-ask-question-wizard-is-live?cb=1) featured meta post that has been there for ages? And you won't have seen the wizard yourself unless you're <111 rep since it was deployed (or navigated to it).

Comment: 1) as per the announcement, if the user is below 111 rep, then they will automatically get the wizard. 2) no, but there's also nothing to prevent the OP from bypassing the wizard steps, blanking each text box, and ending with the current deleted post...

Answer (score 5):

> Can the wizard be summoned by the OP to improve his question when editing?

The Wizard doesn't cover *editing* questions.  It covers *asking* questions.  There currently exists no guided tutorial for users to edit their questions.

For the question you refer...no amount of editing could have improved it.  There's no discernible programming question to ask, so I don't see any value in asking the OP to polish this for absolutely no gain.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Regarding the question referenced in the OP, this was just an example. Many questions could benefit from a _guided_ editing, or more specifically a full rewrite from scratch. For the full rewrite, it might be useful to be able to summon the Wizard in editing mode instead of doing a delete and start a new question as it [affects your account status](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324299/4934172)

Answer (score -13):

> 2. Can the wizard be summoned by the OP to improve his question?

On the [Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?guided=false) page there is a link to [Use guided mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard) (the wizard).

Comment: I could be wrong but I think the OP meant _after_ the question has been posted.

Comment: @Ahmed That would make sense, yeah. So in that case, maybe they (the new contributor) would want to go through the wizard and copy-paste what it outputs, or just delete the original question and go through the wizard instead.

Comment: Yeah I don't think there's an option to edit using the "wizard" but I wouldn't encourage deleting and reposting a question if it can be improved. Please note that deleted questions [affect your account status](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324299/4934172), so in general, you should be a little conservative with that.

Comment: True there is the link on the _Ask-a-Question_ page, but, as indicated by @AhmedAbdelhameed, can it be summoned when the OP wants to _edit_ his question (updated my original post to be more clear).

Comment: Also, the link on the _Ask-a-Question_ page is barely noticeable.