# I've met the requirements for my second Socratic badge, but haven't gotten it - why?

Tags: support, badges

According to the [appropriate query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/229495/progress-towards-curious-inquisitive-and-socratic-badges), I seem to have enough pertinent question days to merit a second Socratic badge; and yet - I [haven't been awarded the badge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1593077/einpoklum?tab=badges). Why is that?

Note: Not a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294497), in which the requirements were not actually met. Mine seem to have been.

Comment: It might be If you've got some non-well received/deleted posts on some of those days - it cancels out that day... Otherwise - badges awarded at certain times - not always instantly... so you're waiting for the badge award script to run...

Comment: @JonClements: So, you're saying the query does not exactly match SO's logic for counting the days?

Comment: @einpoklum yup - as per Stijn's answer... as you're a 10k user you can search for your own deleted posts... using this [search query](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1593077%20is%3aq%20deleted%3a1)

Answer (score 8):

The query isn't 100% accurate, see its description:

> We cannot see deleted questions here so the count is going to be inaccurate, nor does it track your positive question record ratio.

Comment: Is there a way to see deleted questions with the data explorer?

Comment: @einpoklum No, it's not possible.