# Can't receive Bronze Badge (the formula doesn't work)

Tags: bug, badges

My question is not a duplicate of this post: [Why didn't I get the Curious badge?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294497/why-didnt-i-get-the-curious-badge)

I can't receive `Curious` bronze badge due to some bug. I know this formula:

(`totalQuestions`-`negativeQuestions`-`closed`-`earlyDeleted`) / `totalQuestions` >= `0.5`

According to a formula I've got `0.63`

`(19 - 1 - 4 - 2) / 19` = `0.63`

Some time ago I was punished by the moderator for removing the post with an answer. Is it the reason for emergence of this bug?

[image]

Comment: That formula is honestly useless for a user to try and calculate themselves, because you can't see *all* of your deleted posts. You actually have 9 deleted, not 2. 5 of those are downvoted and 1 is closed. Your score is only 0.31.