# Why are my badges not working properly?

Tags: bug, badges

In the screenshot below, there is already an overflow of the count in my ***curious*** badge, yet it's still on my *track your next badge* list. Is there any reason for this behavior? Although completely unrelated, I tried implementing the solution I found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269825/386505). It didn't work.

I'd appreciate if more light can be shed on the reason for this issue. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You don't have the curious badge yet. I assume once the process has run to give you the badge, this problem will disappear.

Comment: Do you have a positive question record? Without that, even if you have 6/5 well received questions on separate days, you wont receive the badge.

Comment: It has been this way for a while (probably weeks). Also, all six questions have a positive vote count.

Comment: Check [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294497/why-didnt-i-get-the-curious-badge), and see if it applies. Otherwise, you'll get the badge later when the batch job runs.

Comment: It's likely that downvoted, deleted questions are keeping your question record from being positive. You just need to ask more questions that are well received.

Comment: You have 9 deleted questions, 4 of which are negatively scored and 2 of which are closed... that all adds up using the formula in the link @yivi gave on how it's calculated.

Comment: I can see that now. There's a "Need positive record" text when I click the "curious" badge. I understand perfectly why this is happening now. Thanks a lot!! :hug:

Comment: I'll mark this as a duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294497/why-didnt-i-get-the-curious-badge now.