# Tasks completed but can't earn badge 'Curious'

Tags: support, badges

As shown below I have already completed tasks to earn the 'Curious' badge but still, I didn't get this. I should have earned this two months before but still, I didn't. 
[image]

How can I earn this badge? and my second question is, is this is a bug or not?

I have already looked [similar questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294497/why-didnt-i-get-the-curious-badge/294498#294498) but none of them helped me yet.

Comment: See [this formula](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294498/957731) and check if you have any deleted questions that's stopping you from having the *"positive question record"* criteria fulfilled

Comment: @ivarni This is a bug, right? If I deleted my questions the progress bar should become empty in that case

Comment: @IndrajithEkanayake You linked the question only after the edit. Just click on “Curious”. Does it say “need positive question record”?

Comment: Yup I linked that question later because it isn't helped me?

Comment: yup, I get that point. But this is a bug, right? If my questions deleted the progress bar should become empty instantly

Comment: No it's not a bug. The progress bar counts the number of days with a positive question, and you've got enough of those. You could argue it's not a very intuitive UI but that's they way they've designed it to work.

Comment: Maybe you didn't look at the answers in the dupe very closely. There is even one that proposes an enhancement to the UI so it's clearer you haven't met the requirements yet.

Comment: Why the progress bar counts only the number of positive questions if there is a formula? So the progress bar should work according to that formula am I right?

Comment: The "progress bar" counts the **number of days** with well received questions, not the number of questions

Comment: So this is a bug in my perspective. The progress bar should work according to the formula then

Comment: Why stackoverflow commiunity can't fix this

Comment: @yivi still I didn't get the answer. If this is not a bug why you can't define the reason for progress bar increasing. Why we can't make it work according to our formula?

Comment: And I already mentioned the duplicated question in my question that marked as a duplicate of me?

Comment: It's not a bug. It's _"not great UI"_, conflated with you doing very little effort to understand it. A bit more digging should have taken you to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFnA7.png), which is much clearer (although not perfect).

Comment: Because the question it's a dupe. If you had read the q&a completely, you would have understood why you didn't get the "curious" badge, and wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: Then if it is a UI matter, as a developer I would like to help to fix this. Is StackOverflow opensource @yivi? If it does I can develop better UI

Comment: Why we can't fix this UI matter?

Comment: The second answer to that question gives better clarification.

Comment: I have understood the reason behind now. But my problem is why we can't develop better UI for this?

Comment: You can bring this UI issue to the moderators' attention

Comment: Yup, I posted this question for that @MerajAlMaksud to access moderators and tell the matter. But no one is with me as I guess. It is better to fix this problem rather than marking the question as duplicate

Comment: @yivi The duplicated question was 4 years old. Which means since 4 years the problem did not solved. So why we can't talk with moderators to take an action now?

Comment: It's marked duplicate because IT IS a duplicate question. You can however reword your question to point out the UI issue.

Comment: You asked this question because you thought there was a bug. You misread both the UI and the information you researched previously. The question was correctly closed as a dupe. What you want is to propose an enhancement, which would be a feature request. I would advise you do better research before posting a new question with your feature request.

Comment: The UI issue has been known for over 4 years, it won't get fixed in the next 5 minutes. The reason it hasn't been fixed in all those years is that SO does not consider it a big enough issue to warrant spending development time on.

Comment: So is it okay to ask another question regarding UI fixing? @yivi

Comment: @yivi That's what I meant. Still, I can't understand what is the reason to increase the progress bar. Which means still I didn't get an answer for my question

Comment: Do you understand this badge has **TWO** different preconditions for being awarded?

Comment: If it is a UI matter why moderators didn't fix the problem along 4years. Whis meens there should be another matter

Comment: @IndrajithEkanayake Moderators don't have access to the code, for one. But the developers probably haven't "fixed" this because there are more important things to work on

Comment: Thankyou @Rob. finally, I found a person who understands me. Now I got an answer to my question. This is the answer what I had looking for

Comment: So, `status-deferred` or `status-declined`?

Comment: For you the numbers are: total = 20, deleted = 7, closed = 4, downvoted = 7, so your ratio is (20 - 7 - 4 - 7) / 20 = 2 / 20 = 0.1. You need an additional 16 questions that are not downvoted, closed or deleted to reach 0.5.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I never asked how the formula works for me. I asked only if this is a bug why people didn't fix this through 4 years. Please read below comments again and then reply

Comment: @IndrajithEkanayake I can read just fine, thanks. No, this isn’t a bug, and I thought you’d like to know your own numbers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters got it, Thnks

Comment: `qualtiy-improvement` and `improvement-request` are not valid tags. See their **tag wiki** for details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you read the details of the `Curious` badge carefully, you'll notice following conditions:

- Ask a well-received question on 5 separate days. That means you need to have 5 questions that have one or more score.
- Maintain a positive question record. Which means none of your recent questions can have negative feedback.

To understand it better, here's an instance of the `Electorate` badge:

[image]

When a condition gets void, system marks with with a silver cross, same as below:

[image]

I admit it's difficult to understand. The developer should have colored it red. But it seems they don't see as a big deal.

**Follow Up:** I've recently got my curious badge. The next badge is the `Inquisitive` badge, which have similar rules to obtain. And this is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: This is not an answer for my question

Comment: Okay, then. @Indrajith Please do as I say. First, go to your profile. Then track the `Curious` badge. Now click on the badge. Could you please take a screenshot of that and add it to your question?

Comment: it says “need positive question record”

Comment: but this is a bug in my opinion? If I deleted my questions the progress bar should become empty. am I right/

Comment: @IndrajithEkanayake If you deleted what questions? The "positive question record" takes deleted questions into account.

Comment: So then why the progress bar increases? That's what I can't understand

Comment: OP doesn't understand that there are two conditions. The former is fulfilled, but the latter isn't.

Comment: So why the progress bar increases if latter isn't ? that's my question

Comment: The progress bar you are talking about is about the first condition which you've already fulfilled. But there is a cross under it which tells that the second condition is not fulfilled. Wait, I'm gonna update my answer with some examples from my profile.